# Remover Nodo de un Arbol Binario de Búsqueda

Tags: c++

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de definir una función para remover un Nodo dentro de un Arbol Binario usando recursión y funciones recursivas dentro de mi clase:

Estructura de mi clase ABB

```
template <class T>
class Conjunto
{
    public:

        // Constructor. Genera un conjunto vacío.
        Conjunto();

        // Destructor. Debe dejar limpia la memoria.
        ~Conjunto();

        // Inserta un elemento en el conjunto. Si este ya existe,
        // el conjunto no se modifica.
        void insertar(const T&);

        // Decide si un elemento pertenece al conjunto o no.
        bool pertenece(const T&) const;

        // Borra un elemento del conjunto. Si este no existe,
        // el conjunto no se modifica.
        void remover(const T&);

        // Siguiente elemento al recibido por párametro, en orden.
        const T& siguiente(const T& elem);

        // Devuelve el mínimo elemento del conjunto según <.
        const T& minimo() const;

        // Devuelve el máximo elemento del conjunto según <.
        const T& maximo() const;

        // Devuelve la cantidad de elementos que tiene el conjunto.
        unsigned int cardinal() const;

        // Muestra el conjunto.
        void mostrar(std::ostream& o) const;

    private:

        struct Nodo
        {
            // El constructor, toma el elemento al que representa el nodo.
            Nodo(const T& v);
            // El elemento al que representa el nodo.
            T valor;
            // Puntero a la raíz del subárbol izquierdo.
            Nodo* izq;
            // Puntero a la raíz del subárbol derecho.
            Nodo* der; 
        };

        bool buscarDesde(Nodo* const &nd, const T& clave) const;
        void destruir(Nodo* raiz);
        void insertarAux(Nodo* nodoIn,Nodo* &raiz);
        void removerDesde(Nodo* &padre, Nodo* &nd, const T& clave ); //remover desde
        //Pre: nd pertenece a  ABB, tengo que recibir por referencia para no crear copias
        void removerAux(Nodo* &padre, Nodo* &nd);
        //Pre: nd != nullptr
        const T& minimoDesde(Nodo* const &nd) const;
        //Pre: nd != nullptr
        const T& maximoDesde(Nodo* const  &nd) const;
        unsigned int contarDesde(Nodo* const &nd) const ;
        const Nodo* buscarNodoDesde(const Nodo* nd, const T& clave) const;
        void mostrarDesde( Nodo* nd, std::ostream& o) const;
        T& minimoDesdeRemove(Nodo* &nd);


        // Puntero a la raíz de nuestro árbol.
        Nodo* _raiz;

};
```

Operación de interfaz:

```
template <class T>
void Conjunto<T>::remover(const T& clave) {

    removerDesde(_raiz, _raiz, clave);

}
```

Funciones Auxiliares de remover:

1 ETAPA: Busco al elemento para posteriormente iniciar la ETAPA 2

```
template<class T>
void Conjunto<T>::removerDesde(Conjunto:: Nodo* &padre, Conjunto::Nodo* &nd, const T &clave) {
    if(nd != nullptr){

       if(nd->valor == clave){ //Lo encontre y lo elimino nd
            removerAux(padre, nd);
       }
       else if(nd->valor < clave){ //vamos a la derecha
           if(padre == nd){

               removerDesde(padre, nd->der, clave);
           }
           else{
               padre = nd; //actualizo al nuevo padre de nd
               removerDesde(padre, nd->der, clave);
           }

       }
       else if(nd->valor > clave){//vamos a la izquierda
           if(padre == nd){

               removerDesde(padre, nd->izq, clave);
           }
           else{
               padre = nd;
               removerDesde(padre, nd->izq, clave);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

ETAPA 2: Una vez identificado el elemento, voy a efectivizar el borrado y reenganchar los punteros del padre próximo de nd con lo que resta de los hijos de nd y todo su subárbol.

```
//Pre: padre efectivamente es el padre (Mas próximo desde arriba de nd) de nd para alguna rama
template<class T>
void Conjunto<T>::removerAux(Conjunto::Nodo* &padre, Conjunto::Nodo* &nd) {

    if(nd != nullptr){
        if(nd->izq == nullptr && nd->der == nullptr){//nd es hoja
            if(nd == padre->izq){
                padre->izq = nullptr;
            }
            if(nd == padre->der){
                padre->der = nullptr;
            }

        }

        else if((nd->izq != nullptr && nd->der == nullptr)||(nd->izq == nullptr && nd->der != nullptr)){ //un solo hijo de los dos
            if(nd == padre->izq){  //identifico donde etaba conecatdo nd
                if(nd->izq != nullptr){
                    padre->izq = nd->izq; //desengancho los nodos de padre a nd
                }
                else{//nd tiene un solo hijo
                    padre->izq = nd->der;
                }
            }
            else if(nd == padre->der){
                if(nd->izq != nullptr){
                    padre->der = nd->izq; //desengancho los nodos de padre a nd
                }
                else{//nd tiene un solo hijo
                    padre->der = nd->der;
                }
            }


        }

        else{//nd->izq != nullptr && nd->der != nullptr
            //sustituyo el eliminado

            nd->valor = minimoDesdeRemove(nd->der); //busco el minimo de los mayores o el maximo de los menores
            //minimo de los mayores
            removerDesde(padre, nd->der, nd->valor);


        }
        delete(nd);
        nd = nullptr;

    }
}
            nd->valor = minimoDesdeRemove(nd->der); //busco el minimo de los mayores o el maximo de los menores
            //minimo de los mayores
            removerDesde(padre, nd->der, nd->valor);


        }
        delete(nd);
        nd = nullptr;

    }
}
```

Auxiliar para buscar el hijo mas izquierdo de todo el arbol (el minimo desde un Nodo de partida)

```
//Pre: nd no null
template<class T>
const T& Conjunto<T>::minimoDesde(Conjunto::Nodo* const &nd) const{
   if(nd->izq == nullptr){
       return nd->valor;
   }
   else{
       minimoDesde(nd->izq);
   }
}
```

Esto no me compila bien porque elimina todo el subarbol de nd, en vez de eliminar solo el nodo que quiero borrar. Entonces padre se queda con muchos menos nodos de los que deberia (elimina mas nodos ademas de nd).
Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de arreglar este código sin tener que cambiar mis parámetros de entrada, porque si los paso por valor, se me van a desapilar una vez termine la ejecución de cada una de las funciones y voy a perder su información, y quiero preservar la parte privada de mi clase.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "*no me compila bien*"? ¿Cuál es el error que recibes?

Comment: Hay errores de test, el numero de elementos esperado en un test es de 2, y el resultado me devuelve la raiz con 1 elemento en vez de los 2 esperados. Hay 1 error de compilación en un test de numero 139 cuando el nodo tiene dos hijos, pueden haber leaks pero eso es algo que todavia no analice porque primero quiero arreglar los problemas de test.